# Git: Combining multiple commits into a single commit

Tags: git, commit, rebase, squash

I am working on a git repository where I do not have any merge write. There are large requirements which requires at least 1-3 weeks to complete. I take out a branch from master and do my changes in it. During this time I generate multiple commits at the end of the day and ensure my code is pushed to remote branch.

Multiple commits on branch code doesn't look great so followed the below link to squash them into one commit using rebase command.

https://blog.carbonfive.com/2017/08/28/always-squash-and-rebase-your-git-commits/

This doesn't seems to be a very good option as the process is long and there are chances of mistake as well.

My Question is, is there any other option I can follow?

Comment: Tell us please why this is a long process. And what kind of mistakes are you thinking about. Thanks.

Comment: "Multiple commits on branch code doesn't look great ".  Strongly disagree.  Many small, understandable commits is better than one giant commit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Depends on the nature of the commits. I have reviewed Pull Requests with 15+ commits with over half of them being "Work in progress", "Pushing updated code", "Remove console log"(multiple of these in a single PR), etc. Small commits can be good but they can also produce noise when you are trying to hunt down a specific commits and in some instances its better to squash

Comment: The problem with commits with messages of the form "work in progress" is not that the commit is small.  It is that the commit message is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible course of action, somewhat simpler and less error-prone than an interactive rebase in some contexts, is to just **undo the commits and re-commit just once for the whole lot**. I also find it quicker.

Let's assume this example tree with 2 branches, `master` and `complex-feature`

```
A-<-B-<-C <<< master
     \
      D-<-E-<-F-<-G-<-H-<-I-<-J-<-K <<< complex-feature
```

Before just merging this long list of commits (`D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K`), you could do the following :

```
git checkout complex-feature
git reset --soft B
git commit -m "Global message for commits D through K"
```

And the tree would look like this afterwards :

```
A-<-B-<-C <<< master
     \
      L <<< complex-feature
```

...where commit `L` contains the sum of all changes from `D` through `K`.

**However, as noted by others, multiple small commits are not a problem, and grouping too many things together can also have nasty side effects. Be sure to discuss with your coworkers and adapt to your workflow.**

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in pushing multiple commits all at once. There may be times when you are working on a sequence of tasks and would require to commit everything only once the task is complete. Other case would require you to do multiple local commits and push each commit only once you are connected to the server.

You could either squash all commits to one or merge each commit to the master branch.

Both the methods are right and there is no right or wrong method. It is up to you to choose which one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can softly reset your branch to specific commit before your edits thus you can commit all of your edits in one single commit.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, multiple commits is not a bad thing -- but a disorganized series of commits can be.

You can use interactive rebase to change commits around by combining reordering, combining and splitting until the resulting order makes sense.

I find this near mandatory for local branches before being pushed to a shared repository.

Just be sure to only do so on a branch that isn't shared.